# How to force delete all versions of objects in S3 bucket and then eventually delete the entire bucket using aws-sdk-go?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-go

I have an S3 bucket with versioning enabled. The bucket has few files which have versions. I have written a sample golang program which can do the following:

- **GetBucketVersioning** - It is able to get bucket versioning status i.e., Enabled
- **ListObjects** - It is able to list the bucket objects
- **DeleteObjects** - It is able to delete the bucket objects (but it just adds 'Delete Marker' only to the latest version of each object. The version history of the objects still remain undeleted)
- **DeleteBucket**: This operation fails with the error message:

> "BucketNotEmpty: The bucket you tried to delete is not empty.
>   You must delete all versions in the bucket."

Could you advise how to force delete **ALL VERSIONS of ALL OBJECTS** in an S3 bucket so that I can ultimately delete the entire bucket, using `aws-sdk-go`, please?

Comment: Delete all the object versions first. Example in Java: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/delete-or-empty-bucket.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, [DeleteBucket](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3@v1.22.0#Client.DeleteBucket) states,

> All objects (including all object versions and delete markers) in the bucket must be deleted before the bucket itself can be deleted.

Now, to delete the versions from a versioning-enabled bucket, we can

1. use [DeleteObject](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3@v1.22.0#Client.DeleteObject), which states,

> To remove a specific version, you must be the bucket owner and you must use the version Id subresource. Using this subresource permanently deletes the version.

2. use [DeleteObjects](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3@v1.22.0#Client.DeleteObjects), which similarly states,

> In the XML, you provide the object key names, and optionally, version IDs if you want to delete a specific version of the object from a versioning-enabled bucket.

I put together a sample program, that I tested against [LocalStack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack), after using the following commands(prerequisites - Docker, Docker Compose, AWS CLI) to create a bucket and populate it with files to include versions.

```sh
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/localstack/localstack/master/docker-compose.yml
export SERVICES="s3"
docker-compose up

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="test"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="test"
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-1"
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3 mb s3://testbucket
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket testbucket --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled
for i in 1 2 3; do
    aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3 cp main.go s3://testbucket/main.go
    aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3 cp go.mod s3://testbucket/go.mod
done

aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3api list-object-versions --bucket testbucket
```

Set the following environment variables before running it

```sh
export AWS_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:4566"
export S3_BUCKET="testbucket"
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3/types"
)

type s3Client struct {
    *s3.Client
}

func main() {
    awsEndpoint := os.Getenv("AWS_ENDPOINT")
    bucketName := os.Getenv("S3_BUCKET")

    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(),
        config.WithEndpointResolverWithOptions(aws.EndpointResolverWithOptionsFunc(
            func(service, region string, options ...interface{}) (aws.Endpoint, error) {
                return aws.Endpoint{
                    URL:               awsEndpoint,
                    HostnameImmutable: true,
                }, nil
            })),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Cannot load the AWS configs: %s", err)
    }

    serviceClient := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    client := &s3Client{
        Client: serviceClient,
    }

    fmt.Printf(">>> Bucket: %s\n", bucketName)

    objects, err := client.listObjects(bucketName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if len(objects) > 0 {
        fmt.Printf(">>> List objects in the bucket: \n")
        for _, object := range objects {
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", object)
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Printf(">>> No objects in the bucket.\n")
    }

    if client.versioningEnabled(bucketName) {
        fmt.Printf(">>> Versioning is enabled.\n")
        objectVersions, err := client.listObjectVersions(bucketName)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        if len(objectVersions) > 0 {
            fmt.Printf(">>> List objects with versions: \n")
            for key, versions := range objectVersions {
                fmt.Printf("%s: ", key)
                for _, version := range versions {
                    fmt.Printf("\n\t%s ", version)
                }
                fmt.Println()
            }
        }

        if len(objectVersions) > 0 {
            fmt.Printf(">>> Delete objects with versions.\n")
            if err := client.deleteObjects(bucketName, objectVersions); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }

            objectVersions, err = client.listObjectVersions(bucketName)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            if len(objectVersions) > 0 {
                fmt.Printf(">>> List objects with versions after deletion: \n")
                for key, version := range objectVersions {
                    fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", key, version)
                }
            } else {
                fmt.Printf(">>> No objects in the bucket after deletion.\n")
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf(">>> Delete the bucket.\n")
    if err := client.deleteBucket(bucketName); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}

func (c *s3Client) versioningEnabled(bucket string) bool {
    output, err := c.GetBucketVersioning(context.TODO(), &s3.GetBucketVersioningInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
    })
    if err != nil {
        return false
    }
    return output.Status == "Enabled"
}

func (c *s3Client) listObjects(bucket string) ([]string, error) {
    var objects []string
    output, err := c.ListObjectsV2(context.TODO(), &s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    for _, object := range output.Contents {
        objects = append(objects, aws.ToString(object.Key))
    }

    return objects, nil
}

func (c *s3Client) listObjectVersions(bucket string) (map[string][]string, error) {
    var objectVersions = make(map[string][]string)
    output, err := c.ListObjectVersions(context.TODO(), &s3.ListObjectVersionsInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    for _, object := range output.Versions {
        if _, ok := objectVersions[aws.ToString(object.Key)]; ok {
            objectVersions[aws.ToString(object.Key)] = append(objectVersions[aws.ToString(object.Key)], aws.ToString(object.VersionId))
        } else {
            objectVersions[aws.ToString(object.Key)] = []string{aws.ToString(object.VersionId)}
        }
    }

    return objectVersions, err
}

func (c *s3Client) deleteObjects(bucket string, objectVersions map[string][]string) error {
    var identifiers []types.ObjectIdentifier
    for key, versions := range objectVersions {
        for _, version := range versions {
            identifiers = append(identifiers, types.ObjectIdentifier{
                Key:       aws.String(key),
                VersionId: aws.String(version),
            })
        }
    }

    _, err := c.DeleteObjects(context.TODO(), &s3.DeleteObjectsInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Delete: &types.Delete{
            Objects: identifiers,
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func (c *s3Client) deleteBucket(bucket string) error {
    _, err := c.DeleteBucket(context.TODO(), &s3.DeleteBucketInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Note in the `listObjectVersions` method, I am mapping the `VersionId`s with the `Key`s.

```golang
    for _, object := range output.Versions {
        if _, ok := objectVersions[aws.ToString(object.Key)]; ok {
            objectVersions[aws.ToString(object.Key)] = append(objectVersions[aws.ToString(object.Key)], aws.ToString(object.VersionId))
        } else {
            objectVersions[aws.ToString(object.Key)] = []string{aws.ToString(object.VersionId)}
        }
    }
```

Then in the `deleteObjects` method, when passing the `ObjectIdentifier`s, I pass the `Key` and the `ObjectId`s for all the versions of an object.

```golang
    for key, versions := range objectVersions {
        for _, version := range versions {
            identifiers = append(identifiers, types.ObjectIdentifier{
                Key:       aws.String(key),
                VersionId: aws.String(version),
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seem to be impossible using the golang sdk.
They didn't implement a delete version function.

Comment: It is possible using the version Id subresource.